# Is it possible to use the pixiedust debugger without the rest of pixidust?

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, pixiedust

Im just interested in the debugger, but do not want my plots being altered by pixiedust. Is it possible to use the debugger, without pixiedust having any other effects?

Answer (score 0):

After 'import pixiedust_node', it just changes the display of cells when you use the library. You can use the debugger without using the rest of pixiedust. Just type '%%pixie_debugger' in the beginning of the cell.

Comment: Could you give a code snippet? When I try to import pixidust_node I am getting a module not found error.